# Is there any way to ignore these SQL warnings on DataGrip?

Tags: sql, database, google-bigquery, datagrip

I use DataGrip as an IDE for Google BigQuery. DataGrip has a warning pane that warns about items that are frivolous. An example below, `"Unable to resolve column 'DAYS_DIFF_CURRENT_ETA'`, this is occurring because I capitalized the word when I was selecting it.

The query runs fine, however I would prefer to only see warnings where my query may not execute due to an error in how I wrote it.

**See the screenshot:**

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be disabled here: File | Settings | Editor | Inspections -> SQL -> Unresolved reference.[image]

Comment: Excellent, thank you that worked. I will be using DataGrip going forward, do you suggest if I have questions to ask it here or on the Jetbrains website?